# aws s3 how to protect against accidental deletion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to have a protection against accidental deletion on our s3 bucket, so i delete an object i can restore it for 1 day before definitive deletion.
What i try:
Enable versionning on the bucket
Create a lifecycle rule with "Permanently delete noncurrent versions of objects", "Delete expired object delete markers or incomplete multipart upload"

[image]

But  with this when i delete an object i can restore it, but if i didn't resstore it it's never definitively deleted

[image]

Comment: How long did you wait after deleting the object? In my experience it can take up to 24 hours for a lifecycle rule to take effect, and your object needs to have been deleted for at least 24 hours before this rule will take effect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I waited over 48 hours. The object in the screenshot was deleted on June 13th so I'll still wait until tomorrow to be sure